# How can i make a side section tracking on my website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, parallax

I have a design, which I wanna build and it has a side tracking section. It tracks on which section the user is and changes the styles. However, I can't find something similar on the Internet and the only thing i think about is to use react-spring/Paralax, but i don't know how yet.
Here is the design of that feature (it's on the right side):
[image]

I would be glad to have some advices at least, what tech/ways should I use to implement this, but if it's not bother you to do it, I provide an App.js file as well:

```
import "./App.css";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar/navbar.component";
import Hero from "./components/hero/hero.component";
import Content from "./components/content/content.component";
import Footer from "./components/footer/footer.component";

import image from './components/content/01.png';
import image2 from './components/content/02.png';
import image3 from './components/content/03.png';


function App() {

  const reverseContainer = {
    direction: "rtl",
  };

  const textBeforeStyle = {
    left: '9.8rem',
  };

  const textStyle = {
    direction: "ltr",
  }


  const pictureStyle = {
    margin: 'auto auto auto -9rem',
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="navbar-container">
        <Navbar />
      </div>
      <Hero />
      <div className="all-content">
        <Content
          textBefore="01"
          textAbove="GEt Started"
          header="What level of hiker are you?"
          mainText="Determining what level of hiker you are can be an important tool when planning future
      hikes. This hiking level guide will help you plan hikes according to different hike
      ratings set by various websites like All Trails and Modern Hiker. What type of hiker
              are you – novice, moderate, advanced moderate, expert, or expert backpacker?"
          image={image}
          side1="right"
          side2="left"
        />
        <Content
          textBefore="02"
          textAbove="Hiking Essentials"
          header="Picking the right Hiking Gear!"
          mainText="The nice thing about beginning hiking is that you don’t really need any special gear, you can probably get away with things you already have.
    Let’s start with clothing. A typical mistake hiking beginners make is wearing jeans and regular clothes, which will get heavy and chafe wif they get sweaty or wet."
          image={image2}
          side1="right"
          side2="left"
          reverseContainer={reverseContainer}
          textBeforeStyle={textBeforeStyle}
          textStyle={textStyle}
          pictureStyle={pictureStyle}
        />
        <Content

          textBefore="03"
          textAbove="where you go is the key"
          header="Understand Your Map & Timing"
          mainText="To start, print out the hiking guide and map. If it’s raining, throw them in a Zip-Lock bag. Read over the guide, study the map, and have a good idea of what to expect. I like to know what my next landmark is as I hike. For example, I’ll read the guide and know that say, in a mile, I make a right turn at the junction.."
          image={image3}
          side1="right"
          side2="left"

        />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: fullpage.js provides a react component, https://alvarotrigo.com/react-fullpage/

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of a way you could do this with React

Build a separate component for each section
in each component make exactly this sidebar but that the part of that component be white and the rest black.
Then build in the css of each component that the white color will enter slowly from the top and disappear slowly from the bottom

this link is to tutrial that i found in youtube that you can make this happen
[check this tutrial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mZ4yguae9Q)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).